Microsoft Office "Add an Author" Popup Data
Where does Windows store its data to fill the PopUp List for the Add an Author field?
I have tried the Registry, the User/Roaming folder, some Outlook address or Contact list, but I've found nothing yet.
Even though this installation is quite new, less than one month old, there are hundreds of records, from previously opened files.
Ref.Microsoft Office 2021, Windows 11.


I think you have answered your very own question -- from "previously opened files". Your Windows keeps scanning all your files (as we speak), using Windows Indexing Service and populates lists like this. It doesn't matter that you have a fairly new computer. What matters is that you probably have a lot of older Office files stored on it. And these files have even more metadata entries that your Windows would love to crunch (and send to Microsoft server by the way). Right-click some of your documents or Excel sheets, hit "Properties" and go to "Details" tab. There you go! :)

Semantics corrected. I mean store, not get.

But the answer is still quite similar. AFAIK, it stores this data in Windows Indexing Service's cache or internal files. If you want to either delete them or read them on your own, you might have a quite hard way to work with these internals.
